# How to combine two video responses using javascript?

Tags: javascript, video, video-streaming, html5-video

I am trying to combine small video responses into one like youtube did. How to combine videos using javascript?

Answer (score 3):

Youtube is doing this using the [Media Source Extensions](https://w3c.github.io/media-source/) API.

You can see samples players (made by Google themselves) in [dash-player](http://dash-mse-test.appspot.com/dash-player.html) and [shaka player](https://github.com/google/shaka-player).

Comment: Xavier you have to ask another question about this. But first please read the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking.